# Error when extracting text from pdf using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

[sample pdf](http://ishouhuo.cn/cannotExtract.pdf)

Sample pdf is a chinese resume, 3 pages, using standard code below

```
PDDocument document =  PDDocument.load(new File(path));
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
text = stripper.getText(document);
```

Extraction result is like below image, only some words

[image: extraction result]

Comment: What you got ? An error ou it simply does nothing ?

Comment: *"cannot extrac text"* - what does that mean? Does some error occur or is the extracted text simply not what you expect? (Incomplete, wrong,...)

Comment: sample pdf is a chinese resume, 3 pages, extraction result is not complete as image shows

Comment: It's look like parsing error from the Chinese I suggest you to try with ipdf library.

Comment: Does your system have a Chinese language-pack installed? Otherwise I don't see how it would be able to display the extracted text in plain-text. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Did you read these? pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#text-extraction And what PDFBox version are you using? Did you get any log messages?

Answer (score 3):

If you run the text extraction code and enable logging, you'll see numerous warnings:

```
Feb 12, 2019 5:45:58 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font toUnicode
WARN: No Unicode mapping for CID+5482 (5482) in font GNPVNR+PingFangSC-Semibold
Feb 12, 2019 5:45:58 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font toUnicode
WARN: No Unicode mapping for CID+1842 (1842) in font GNPVNR+PingFangSC-Semibold
Feb 12, 2019 5:45:58 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font toUnicode
WARN: No Unicode mapping for CID+7566 (7566) in font GNPVNR+PingFangSC-Semibold
Feb 12, 2019 5:45:58 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font toUnicode
WARN: No Unicode mapping for CID+1915 (1915) in font GNPVNR+PingFangSC-Semibold
...
```

Indeed, when inspecting the PDF one sees that there are numerous subsets of PingFangSC styles embedded but each time

- with a **ToUnicode** map without any entries at all,
- with an **Identity-H** encoding, and
- with an *Adobe-Identity-0* **ROS**,

i.e. without any information which glyph represents which Unicode code point. Thus, it should not surprise at all that text extraction results are very lacking.

So if you really need to extract the text, ask the source of the PDF to provide a copy which includes the required information. If that is not possible, try OCR.

---

By the way, a good first check usually is to try and copy&paste the text from Adobe Reader. In the case at hand that also results in mostly missing characters. That usually means that the information required for text extraction according to the PDF specification is missing.

You'll also find some more backgrounds at the link @Tilman provided in a comment: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#text-extraction

Comment: Thx a lot, it is a little complicated, I need some time to comprehend and verify the answer