# Can tabula deal with Chinese characters?

Tags: cjk, tabula

I got the following WARNING message:

```
No Unicode mapping for CID+2716 (2716) in font KMNIME+DFHei-Md-80-GB
```

Is **tabula** able to deal with font KMNIME+DFHei-Md-80-GB ??

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tabula definitely can work with Chinese characters, maybe it's because of your charset setting of your computer. Try adding `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` to your java command

Comment: Java command? I'm actually using tabula-py. And the default encoding is already **utf-8**.

Comment: I mean, it is using **utf-8** to decode/encode, but it might be just lack of the particular font. So I downloaded that particular font already, and have it installed via **font-manager**, but still NOT working. Let me reboot and take another try....

Answer (score 0):

Some files have non-standard mappings of Unicode code points to font glyphs. It is usually quite difficult to remap them.

Here's more information: [Error when extracting text from pdf using pdfbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54644435/error-when-extracting-text-from-pdf-using-pdfbox)